# Using custom Rcpp class in rcpp-function in an R-package. Both class and function are defined in the same .cpp file

Tags: r, arrays, rcpp

I'm trying to speed up a loop over the dimensions of an R-array using Rcpp.
The array class is from the rcpp-gallery: (https://github.com/RcppCore/rcpp-gallery/blob/gh-pages/src/2014-03-21-simple-array-class.Rmd

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

/*
  ******************************************************************************
  Offset and Array classes based on code by Romain Francois copied from
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/5932 on 2014-01-07.
******************************************************************************
  */
  
  class Offset{
    private:
      IntegerVector dim ;
    
    public:
      Offset( IntegerVector dim ) : dim(dim) {}
    
    int operator()( IntegerVector ind ){
      int ret = ind[0] ;
      int offset = 1 ;
      for(int d=1; d < dim.size(); d++) {
        offset = offset * dim[d-1] ; 
        ret = ret + ind[d] * offset ;
      }
      return ret ;
    } ;
    
    IntegerVector getDims() const {
      return(dim) ;
    };
    
  } ;

class Array : public NumericVector {
  private:
    // NumericVector value;
  Offset dims ;
  
  public:
    //Rcpp:as
  Array( SEXP x) : NumericVector(x), 
  dims( (IntegerVector)((RObject)x).attr("dim") ) {}
  
  Array( NumericVector x,  Offset d ): NumericVector(x), 
  dims(d) {}
  
  Array( Dimension d ): NumericVector( d ), dims( d ) {}
  
  IntegerVector getDims() const {
    return(dims.getDims());
  };
  
  NumericVector getValue()  const {
    return(*((NumericVector*)(this)));
  };
  
  inline double& operator()( IntegerVector ind) {
    int vecind = dims(ind);
    NumericVector value = this->getValue();  
    return value(vecind);
  } ;
  
  // change dims without changing order of elements (!= aperm)
  void resize(IntegerVector newdim) {
    int n = std::accumulate((this->getDims()).begin(), (this->getDims()).end(), 1, 
                            std::multiplies<int>());
    int nnew = std::accumulate(newdim.begin(), newdim.end(), 1, 
                               std::multiplies<int>());
    if(n != nnew)  stop("old and new old dimensions don't match.");
    this->dims = Offset(newdim);
  } ;
  
} ;

namespace Rcpp {
  // wrap(): converter from Array to an R array
  template <> SEXP wrap(const Array& A) {
    IntegerVector dims = A.getDims();
    //Dimension dims = A.getDims();
    Vector<REALSXP> x = A;
    x.attr( "dim" ) = wrap(dims);
    return x; 
  }
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
int runloop(Array& myarray) {
  IntegerVector myarrayDims  = myarray.getDims();
  for (int j = 0; j < myarrayDims[1]; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < myarrayDims[2]; k++) {
      for (int l = 0; l < myarrayDims[3]; l++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myarrayDims[0]; i++) {
          myarray({i, j, k, l}) = i + j + k +l;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sourcing and executing this code from an interactive R session works as intended.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(file.path(".", "minimalExample.cpp"))

inputArray <- array(data = rnorm(10^4), dim = c(10, 10, 10, 10))
runloop(inputArray)
inputArray
```

But when I move the .cpp file into the src-folder of my R package structure, the build fails, because the class Array is not recognized ([see screenshot of build errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIDlm.png))

The content of the RcppExports.cpp after the failed build is as follows:

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// runloop
int runloop(Array& myarray);
RcppExport SEXP _foobar_runloop(SEXP myarraySEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Array& >::type myarray(myarraySEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(runloop(myarray));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_foobar_runloop", (DL_FUNC) &_foobar_runloop, 1},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_foobar(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

How can i get my simple loop running?
Thanks :)

ps: my sessionInfo() in R-Studio returns:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_1.0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a saying that you need to walk before you can run.  You missed the jogging step between the walk and the sprint ;-).

Having code that compiles in a single function that you source is *not* the same as having it in a full-blown package.  What you desire to do *can be done* and has been done. In short, while you have the code wrote in the *source* file, it also needs to be present in the *generated file* `src/RcppExports.cpp`.

One trick you are missing now is described in the Rcpp Attributes vignette in the section *Types in Generated Code*, and I quote (editing out markdown/latex)

> ### Types in Generated Code
>
> In some cases the signatures of the C++ functions that are generated within
> `RcppExports.cpp` may have additional type requirements beyond the core
> standard library and `Rcpp` types (e.g. `CharacterVector`,
> `NumericVector`, etc.). Examples might include convenience typedefs,
> as/wrap handlers for marshaling between custom types and SEXP, or types
> wrapped by the Rcpp `XPtr` template.
>
> In this case, you can create a header file that contains these type definitions
> (either defined inline or by including other headers) and have this header
> file automatically included in `RcppExports.cpp`. Headers named with
> the convention `pkgname_types` are automatically included along with
> the generated C++ code. For example, if your package is named `fastcode`
> then any of the following header files would be automatically included in
> `RcppExports.cpp`:
>
> ```
> src/fastcode_types.h
> src/fastcode_types.hpp
> inst/include/fastcode_types.h
> inst/include/fastcode_types.hpp
> ```
>
> [...]